# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to\infty}\sqrt[n]{3^n +n^32^n}$ by comparing it with the limits of two other sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> How do I find
> $$\lim_{n \to\infty}\sqrt[n]{3^n +n^32^n}$$ by comparing it with other two sequences?

I am struggling to find two sequences such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} z_n$
$$x_n \leq \sqrt[n]{3^n +n^32^n} \leq z_n ,  \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

I used
$x_n = \sqrt[n]{3^n} $
but I am not sure what to take as $z_n$. I checked on Wolfram, but the relation does not hold for some $n$. Is there a method to compare this sequence  that I am missing? http://ru.solverbook.com/spravochnik/teoremy/teorema-o-dvux-milicionerax/ The first example is somehow similar, but I cannot understand how they find the last inequality.

Comment: For example, take $z_n=\sqrt[n]{3^n+n^33^n}$. It isn't difficult to show it tends to $3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have

$$3=\sqrt[n]{3^n}\le \sqrt[n]{3^n +n^32^n}\le\sqrt[n]{3^n +n^33^n}=3\sqrt[n]{1+n^3}.$$

Since the limit of $\sqrt[n]{1+n^3}$ is $1$, you are done.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

For large $n:$

$3^n< 3^n+n^32^n <2 \cdot 3^n. $

Appended:

$(3/2)^n=$

$e^{n\log (3/2)}>(n^4\log^4 (3/2))/4!$;

Archimedean principle:

There is a $n_0 \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ s.t.

$n_0 >4!/(\log^4 (3/2))$;

For $n\ge n_0$ the inequality

$n^3<(n^4 \log^4 (3/2))/4!<(3/2)^n$ holds.

Used:

$e^x = 1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+.....$